# Duplicate Australian E-Commerce site

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a WordPress ECommerce site targetted for US customers.
I am planning to launch a different site for Customers in Australia.

As I will be selling the same products the website/information will be the same for the most part. The product prices will reflect the local pricing and competition.

Overtime there will be more differences but to begin with I want to duplicate my US site and change the prices and a few pages.

I definitely do not want to get penalized for duplicate content by Google. What is the best strategy ? Should I go with a subdomain or a totally new Top level domain. So currently if I have abc.com should i be going with Australia.abc.com or abc.com.au ? How do I properly achieve this ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should set rel alternate hreflangs on both sites -

`<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com.au" hreflang="en-au" />on example.com`
and

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com" hreflang="en-us" /> on example.com.au
```

2. then you sholud set targeting site content to a specific country (geotargeting) in Google search console for - example.com - United States, for abc.com.au you don't need to do anythong because it's country specific domain